# How to add an ALAsset to the Photo Stream?

Tags: ios, icloud, alassetslibrary, alasset

I tried to add an ALAsset to the Photo Stream, but it looks like this is not possible.
Any suggestions?

I tried the following:

```
typedef void(^SaveImageCompletion)(NSError* error);

-(void)addAssetURL:(NSURL*)assetURL toPhotoStreamWithCompletionBlock:(SaveImageCompletion)completionBlock
{
    [self enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupPhotoStream usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {

        if (group) {
            *stop = YES;
            [self assetForURL: assetURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                if ([group addAsset: asset]) {
                    NSLog(@"Added to photo stream!");
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"ERROR! Adding to photo stream failed!");
                }
                                 completionBlock(nil);

            } failureBlock: completionBlock];
            return;
        }

    } failureBlock: completionBlock];    
}
```

However, addAsset: always fails. It works with regular albums..

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I just found out, that the editable property of the ALAssetsGroup of the Photo Stream is set to NO, so I think it's not possible to write in that group that way.

Comment: Yes, you can only Write to the camera roll and to albums created on the device itself.

Comment: Too bad, I think this API is not really usable for now. You even cannot remove assets from your own album or rename the album...

Comment: Yep apple considers deleting anything from the photo library as too dangerous. Hasn't changed since the API was introduced in iOS 4.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with iOS 8 Apple has created the Photos framework to do such things.

There is an extensive [Photos framework sample project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Introduction/Intro.html).